# Echo taxonomy name - second level

Tags: taxonomy, archives, terms

I have the following taxonomy:

**Location:**

```
Province
--City
----Suburb
Province
--City
----Suburb
```

How can I echo the names of "Suburb" (second level) on an archive page?

So, for example:

**Location:**

```
Western Cape
--Cape Town
----Tokai
```

How can I echo ONLY "Tokai"?

**Edit:**

This is my archive.php (reached via two SELECT dropdowns on homepage):

```
echo esc_attr(get_search_query());

//FIRST QUERY
$args = array(
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'orderby' => 'modified',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        );

//SECOND QUERY
$args2 = array (
...different args for second query...
);

$new_args = http_build_query($args);
$query = new WP_Query($query_string.'&'.$new_args);


if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
the_title();
the_post_thumbnail();
<need the taxonomy name to go here (3rd child)>
```

Comment: You left out important detail like exactly where will this be used, is it on a taxonomy archive template, for posts inside the loop or a single post

Comment: @PieterGoosen I did specify that :) "On an archive page". So I'd like to output a list of posts as: Title, Date, Taxonomy (location) using archive.php

Comment: Archive page can date, post type, author, taxonomy, category or tag page ;-)

Comment: Also note that if you are on a taxonomy page, `get_queried_object()` holds the current term being viewed

Comment: @PieterGoosen Ok:) I've updated my question to include all the relevant info :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that code to retrieve the last taxonomy term in your taxonomy list:

in your **functions.php** file create a custom function:

```
function my_custom_function() {
    global $post;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'location' );
    if (!empty($terms)) {
        foreach($terms as $term) {
            if (!get_term_children($term->term_id, 'location')) {
                echo $term->name;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When, inside your **archive.php** you should call newly created custom function:

```
if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
the_title();
the_post_thumbnail();
<need the taxonomy name to go here (3rd child)>
<?php my_custom_function(); ?>
```

Result:

[image: results]

[image]

Comment: @Guit4eva you welcome! 8) If you have any other question, feel free to reach me on http://twitter.com/keeprockinit